# Azure AD OpenId Auth not working when inhereted Authorize Attribute

Tags: c#, azure, inheritance, azure-active-directory, onauthorization

I try to authenticate users for an azure app service written in C# 4.7.2 full framework.

The authentication is made true OpenId on an Azure AD.

It works well when using the [Authorize] attribute on a controller.

When I try to decorate the controller with an inhereted from AuthorizeAttribute attribute, the authentication is not anymore based on Azure Ad (in cloud or via iisexpress/localhost)

I need to override the OnAuthorize method because the app displays different data based on a context, and that context must match some users security group.

ie : 
   the urls /context1 and /context2 play the same code but the dbs requests will differ with a "where context = @context" condition. All urls will be prefixed by /context1 or /context2.

Here is the concerned code :

```
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            //https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims/
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            string authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"]}";
            string client = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = client,
                    Authority = authority,
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        RoleClaimType = "groups",
                    },
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                    {
                        RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
                        //MessageReceived = OnMessageReceived,
                        //SecurityTokenValidated = OnSecurityTokenValidated,
                        //AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                        //SecurityTokenReceived = OnSecurityTokenReceived
                    }
                });
        }
```

The "OnRedirectToIdentityProvider" helps me check if azure AD authentication is called.

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext context)
        {
            //OnRedirectToIdentityProvider has not been called
            //Checking that the authenticated user is in the right
            //security group to grant access to /context1 or /context2
        }
}
```

I hoped the Startup.cs configuration will be called after OnAuthorize overriden.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for a response and trying to simplifying authorizations, I had another problem and found the answer while searching for it.

To continue to authenticate against Azure AD, you can override the AuthorizationCore method.

Here is the new code :

```
 public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase context)
        {
            if (!base.AuthorizeCore(context))
                return false;
            //Custom actions
        }
    }
```

Regards.